# Notification icon on API Level 26

Tags: android, push-notification

I don't understand which icon android api 26 use for push notification when app is close. When I receive push notification it's always default icon with droid.

I remove all default icon from ressources, set `android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` (ic_launcher is a png)

Edit :
My issue is when this is the system tray display the notification https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: change your notification after using it once.. cause sometimes the old notification id persists if you change any attribute change the id..

Answer (score 0):

The icon which you have set in notification object is display

```
notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```

For Example

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            resultIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Notification notification;
    Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notificationsound);
 notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.lg_logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSound(sound)
                .build();
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: the issue is when it is the system tray that display the notification

Answer (score 0):

user `notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);` to set the small icon also when using an image don't make it larger than 250px X 250px.

Comment: the issue is when it is the system tray that display the notification

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in You `Manifest.xml`

```
           <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
           <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Also, Make sure icon you have generated is as per the guidelines provided by Google.
[Here is official guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html)

Comment: I have already did it, works well on android 7.1.2 but not on 8.0